# Why doesn't time.Sleep(2) work with go routines?

Tags: go

From the go routine example here: https://gobyexample.com/goroutines, why doesn't replacing the `fmt.Scanln` code with a `time.sleep(2)` work?

If you replace the last three lines with `time.Sleep(2)`, the go routines don't print anything.

```
func main() {
    f("direct")
    go f("goroutine")
    go func(msg string) {
        fmt.Println(msg)
    }("going")

    time.Sleep(2)
}
```

Comment: 2 nanoseconds is not enough ;)

Comment: `time.Sleep` takes `Duration` as an argument, which is in nanoseconds. You're sleeping for two nanoseconds. If you want seconds, use `time.Sleep(2*time.Second)`.

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks.  One of you can post as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`time.Sleep`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Sleep) takes [`time.Duration`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration) as an argument, which is in nanoseconds. If you want seconds, use `time.Sleep(2*time.Second)`:

```
f("direct")
go f("goroutine")
go func(msg string) {
    fmt.Println(msg)
}("going")

time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/lgKSyAW4RO.

But it's always better to use channels or tools from package [`sync`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/) for synchronisation.